# GKE upgrading Kubernetes cluster from 1.21.6-gke.1500 to 1.22.3-gke.1500 fails

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've noticed that Kubernetes 1.22.3-gke.1500 version is available in GKE's Regular channel. My cluster is in version 1.21.6-gke.1500 (master and node pool). I am trying to upgrade to newer version, but I get an error:

> Master version "1.22.3-gke.1500" is unsupported.

No further explanations or details. Why is the newer version unsupported? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gcloud container get-server-config --region {your-region}` to see what versions your region supports. For example, I'm in europe-west2

```
$ gcloud container get-server-config --region europe-west2
Fetching server config for europe-west2
channels:
- channel: RAPID
  defaultVersion: 1.22.3-gke.1500
  validVersions:
  - 1.23.1-gke.500
  - 1.22.4-gke.1501
  - 1.22.3-gke.1500
  - 1.22.3-gke.700
  - 1.21.6-gke.1500
  - 1.21.5-gke.1802
- channel: REGULAR
  defaultVersion: 1.21.6-gke.1500
  validVersions:
  - 1.21.6-gke.1500
  - 1.21.5-gke.1802
  - 1.20.12-gke.1500
  - 1.20.11-gke.1801
- channel: STABLE
  defaultVersion: 1.20.12-gke.1500
  validVersions:
  - 1.21.5-gke.1802
  - 1.20.12-gke.1500
  - 1.20.11-gke.1801
  - 1.20.11-gke.1300
  - 1.19.15-gke.1801
...
```

So in this scenario, if your cluster is on RAPID channel, then 1.22.3-gke.1500 is supported. But if it's on REGULAR or STABLE, it will not be.

Additionally, the updates to the available releases may take a few days. Just because a release note might say it's available does not mean its immediately available.

Comment: Thank, you. Indeed it wasn't listed in gcloud.

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: thanks for this useful command!
In us-central1 it looks like the version is available in the stable channel, but Im still getting the unsupported error hopefully it will resolve in few days

Comment: @Benda yep, the updates take a few days to propagate, so give it time and the updates should show up eventually. We got caught out ourselves when an upgrade took place as per release notes a week prior.